# Font weight set as normal but is displaying in bold on browser

Tags: html, css

I have font weight set to normal for .meta, .sender, .to, and .receiver. However, this still shows the text as bold for all the content in the middle of the box. I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong and why it's not changing to normal.

```html
<table class="label">
  <tr>
    <td class="sign">F</td>
    <td class="holder">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="internet-base">
          Internert Base
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          FIRST-CLASS<br />
          ePostage<br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="title">FIRST-CLASS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="row">
      <p class="sender">
        {{fromName}}
        <br />
        {{refNumber}} <br />
      </p>
      <p class="meta">
        Email Date: {{labelDate}}
        <br />
        Memory: {{emailWeight}} kb
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="receiver">
       <!-- <p class="signature">SIGNATURE WAIVED</p> -->
      <p class="to" style="padding-top: 10px">
        {{toName}}
        <br />
        {{toRefNumber}}<br />
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="barcode">
      <p class="note">TRACKING # EP</p>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{barImage}}" alt="" class="img" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="footer"><img src="https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/vector/sad-panda-hidden-in-the-white-background-47723-2880x1800.jpg" width="93" height="29"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  @import url("http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9");

  @page {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  * {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  }

  p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .label {
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .sign {
    font-size: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 37px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
  }

  .barcode {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  }

  .img {
    width: 70%;
  }

  .footer {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
  }

  .row {
    height: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .signature {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .meta {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal; 
  }

  .sender {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: initial;
    font-weight: normal; 
  }

  .to {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal; 
  }

  .receiver {
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    font-weight: normal; 
  }

  .box {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .holder {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
  }

  .note {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .flexbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .internet-base {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  /* New */
  
  .footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer img {
      margin-right: 45px;
  }

</style>
```

All of the below content should not be in bold:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look bold to me (or like a data structure that is appropriate to express with a table)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with chrome on windows using the 'helvetica' font, have you tried looking at this with a different browser/on a different OS? Or with a different font? At least, that's what i found in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/811097/helvetica-fonts-always-rendering-as-bold-in-chrome

Comment: You could try setting an explicit font weight like `400` instead of `normal`. Normal might be interpreted differently based on the browser. In your snippet it's bold but when I put it in a jsfiddle it's "normal"

Comment: This is related to your use of the font Helvetica Neue. How are you loading that font or are you assuming it is already available? At least in  my Edge/Chrome and Firefox on Windows10 it seems to be picking up Helvetica Neue Bold only so setting font weights isn't going to have any affect.

Comment: @AHaworth I am importing from CDN Fonts.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I missed that. It's a missing www in the address (don't ask me to explain the full details!). Have put up a snippet in an answer to show you can now get 'normal' weight

Comment: @Quentin wouldn't one need to use a table to get maximum compatibility with email systems? Sending a label for a user to print out might well be something that's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the way the font file is being addressed.

Adding a www to the url in the import has cured it at least for me on Edge/Chrome and Firefox on Windows10. A 'normal' weight font is now picked up.

```html
<table class="label">
  <tr>
    <td class="sign">F</td>
    <td class="holder">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="internet-base">
          Internert Base
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          FIRST-CLASS<br /> ePostage
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="title">FIRST-CLASS</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="row">
      <p class="sender">
        {{fromName}}
        <br /> {{refNumber}} <br />
      </p>
      <p class="meta">
        Email Date: {{labelDate}}
        <br /> Memory: {{emailWeight}} kb
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="receiver">
      <!-- <p class="signature">SIGNATURE WAIVED</p> -->
      <p class="to" style="padding-top: 10px">
        {{toName}}
        <br /> {{toRefNumber}}
        <br />
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="barcode">
      <p class="note">TRACKING # EP</p>
      <img src="data:image/png;base64, {{barImage}}" alt="" class="img" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="footer"><img src="https://cdn.suwalls.com/wallpapers/vector/sad-panda-hidden-in-the-white-background-47723-2880x1800.jpg" width="93" height="29"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
  @import url("http://www.fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9");
  @page {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  * {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  }
  
  p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .label {
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .sign {
    font-size: 140px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 37px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
  }
  
  .barcode {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-top: 4px solid black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  }
  
  .img {
    width: 70%;
  }
  
  .footer {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  
  .row {
    height: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  .signature {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .meta {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .sender {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: initial;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .to {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .receiver {
    font-size: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .box {
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 13px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  .holder {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
  }
  
  .note {
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  .flexbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .internet-base {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  /* New */
  
  .footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .footer img {
    margin-right: 45px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look bold to me but if you think
It is bold then just use a font from [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com) with less font weight (like 400 or 300).

And then apply it in CSS:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Font-Family-Name', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```